# Raphael Animation - Element getting bigger when moving mouse in&out fast on the element

Tags: javascript, raphael, mousehover

I've tried to animate an element with mouse enter/leave using raphael's animation to something like this: raphaelElement.animate({ transform: "...S1.6,1.6" }, 25, 'bounce') for mouseenter and raphaelElement.animate({ transform: "t0, 0" }, 25, 'bounce'); for mouseleave.
Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/junca/Q4L6T/

```
var canvas = Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas"), 100, 100);

var rect = canvas.rect(1, 1, 50, 50);
rect.attr({'fill': 'red'});

hoverFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "...s1.6,1.6"}, 500, 'bounce');
    console.log('mouse enter');
};
hideFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "t0, 0"}, 500, 'bounce');      
    console.log('mouse leave');
};
rect.hover(hoverFunc, hideFunc);
```

The problem is that the element is getting bigger and bigger when moving mouse in&out of the box fast back and forth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use the '...' notation to add the transform, I suspect you want to remove this, and include the original transform string instead, so it always starts fresh.

So instead of

```
rect.animate({transform: "...s1.6,1.6"}, 500, 'bounce');
```

try

```
rect.animate({transform:  originalForm.toString() + "s1.6,1.6"}, 500, 'bounce');
```

I've also correct a few typos in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4L6T/1/)